# Worklight: save notifications in jsonStore when notification been received by device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using worklight for my hybrid application. I have implemented push notification which is notifying to my device. I want to pass notification to jsonstore when its been received by my device.

I am using this piece of code.

```
WL.Client.Push.onMessage = function (props, payload) {

//jsonStore code

//end of jsonStore code

    WL.SimpleDialog.show("FMB Notification", "Provider notification data: " + JSON.stringify(props), [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {
            WL.SimpleDialog.show("FMB Notification", "Application notification data: " + JSON.stringify(payload), [ {
                text : 'Close',
                handler : function() {}
              }]);      
        }
    }]);
};
```

Also I am not able to receive notification when app is open.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not able to receive notifications, why are you asking about storing them? I would imagine you will want to fix the latter in order to achieve the former... and that said - don't ask two questions in 1 question.

You do not explain what is this app that you are unable to receive push with when the app is opened. Is it iOS or Android or something else? Is it event source notifications or tag notifications? Are you certain it is properly configured? What is your MFPF version, build number? Did you follow the sample app? Is *that* working for you, but yours doesn't? Where is your *full* implementation?

Since you failed to provide any meaningful information, my suggestion to you is to take the sample application, configure it and see that you are able to receive notifications "when the app is open".

Once you get that, you can take the JSONStore sample, which demonstrates initializing a storing and saving data in it.

From there on, the road to combining the existing API calls from one sample into anothr in order to save the notification's payload value is clear.